# PHP session isn't starting

Tags: php

```
<?php
   session_start();
?>
 <?php

         if (isset($_SESSION["useruid"])) {
           echo "<span li class='sign'><a href='dash.php'>Profile Page</a></li>";
           echo "<span li class='sign'><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>";
         }
         else {
           echo "<span li class='sign'><a span class='inline-block text-black no-underline hover:text-gray-800 hover:text-underline py-2 px-4' href='signup.php'>Sign Up</a></span></li>";
           echo "<span li class='sign'><a span class='inline-block text-black no-underline hover:text-gray-800 hover:text-underline py-2 px-4' href='login.php'>Sign in</a></span></li>";
           
         }
       ?>
```

I've got a login form that works, but when the user logs in it doesn't display the session but rather says login was successful and goes to the else statement.

Edit - functions below for login form

```
function emptyInputLogin($username, $pwd) {
    $result;
    if (empty($username) || empty($pwd)) {
        $result = true;
    }
    else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}
function loginUser($conn, $username, $pwd) {
    $uidExists = uidExists($conn, $username);

    if ($uidExists === false) {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=wronglogin");
        exit();
    }

    $pwdHashed = $uidExists["usersPwd"];
    $checkPwd = password_verify($pwd, $pwdHashed);

    if ($checkPwd === false) {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=wronglogin");
        exit();
    }
    else if ($checkPwd === true) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $uidExists["usersId"];
        $_SESSION["useruid"] = $uidExists["usersUId"];
        header("location: ../dash.php?loginsuccessful");
        exit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the login code? Are you sure you're setting it in `useruid`?

Comment: Is that `session_start()` in the top of the file, before any output at all? If not, move it to some place before you output anything (you can't even have a single space/line break or anything before it). Looking at the posted code, it looks like it's called in the middle of the page?

Comment: Did you set $_SESSION["useruid"] = true ?

Comment: I added the functions above the login form uses

Comment: Try to add in your login function: echo $uidExists["usersId"]; what are get?

Comment: it's there at the very bottom right below the "else if ($checkPwd === true)"

Comment: the session start is at the very top of the document